# Reference an embedded font from Nuget package containing ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, fonts, nuget, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I have WPF Class Library project, which contains *Fonts* folder with set of *.ttf files. ResourceDictionary *Fonts.xaml* in *Themes* folder has records for each font file. For example:
`<FontFamily x:Key="inter-black">pack://application:,,,/DesignSystem;component/Fonts/#Inter Black</FontFamily>`
This project is targeted to two platforms: .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6. Also it produces the Nuget package also targeting mentioned platforms.
Two sample applications (.NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6 based accordingly) refer to the same Nuget package. It's a valid case, cause the package contains two assemblies for these platforms. Both sample applications have the same content: *App.xaml* file embeds the ResourceDictionary from referred Nuget package:
`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/DesignSystem;component/themes/Fonts.xaml" />`
The main window has two TextBlock instances:

```
        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inter-black}" Text="Sample Text" />
        <TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/DesignSystem;component/Fonts/#Inter Black" Text="Sample Text" />
```

In .NET Framework 4.8 based sample app both TextBoxes looks the same, the custom font is applied. In .NET 6 based app referring to the font via StaticResource works incorrectly.
In the LiveTree properties for the first TextBox I can see, that the value looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCaYH.png)

I also tried to create a local resource record in sample application:
`<FontFamily x:Key="inter-black-local">pack://application:,,,/DesignSystem;component/Fonts/#Inter Black</FontFamily>`
and it does the trick, the font is applied correctly.

So what's wrong? Why it behaves differently in .NET Framework and .NET 6 and how to fix it?

Comment: You should not use any relative path with ttf files. If you do, you have a memory leak per usage.  You should instead make them content files, work out the path in code and use an absolute path

Comment: What about this article from MS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications
It provides several options on including fonts into application.

Comment: You think that's some sort of guarantee against the memory leak bug?